# Keyboard sequence to click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I would like a system administrator to easily create new accounts in an application. I was thinking keys alt and shift would trigger the "Create New User" button or `defaultButton2` in my application. I can get one key to work, but combining both keys doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input").bind("keydown", function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : 
          (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
    if (keycode == 16 && keycode == 18) {
        document.getElementById('defaultButton2').click();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Because `keycode` only takes a single value. So it cannot be both `16` and `18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keydown event ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)) has booleans for the shiftkey, altkey and control key to detect when combinations of buttons are pressed. You can therefore just check those. The keyCode is only for the last key pressed.

If you want to detect other keys, e.g. if "a" and "s" are pressed at the same time, you need to mess around with custom keydown and keyup events and track things yourself.

```js
$('body').on( 'keydown', function(e) {
  if( e.altKey && e.shiftKey ) {
    console.log( "Both pressed!" );
  }
} );
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click Here
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it right...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keydown(function(e) {
    // 18 is the key for alt
    if(e.keyCode == 18 && e.shiftKey) {
        $("button").click();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oa5oa9tp/) and if you're looking for the JS keycodes have a look [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).